# codeigniter hide mode re-write hide index.php in url not work with local host

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I'm using mamp or mac os, codeigniter version 2.1.3. Codeigniter folder structure is as default. it's pretty basic.

I want to hide the index.php in the url. How would you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `.htaccess`file to this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

With that, the homepage and "reg" page load fine without `index.php` for me.